# Why integer value change after JSON.parse call

Tags: javascript, node.js

Code :

```
var string = '{"id": 2,"process_id": 1123565935011360768}';
console.log('Before JSON.parse:',string);
string = JSON.parse(string);
console.log('After JSON.parse:',string);
```

Output :

```
Before JSON.parse: {"id": 2,"process_id": 1123565935011360768}
After JSON.parse: {id: 2, process_id: 1123565935011360800}
```

Why JSON.parse change process_id ?
It somehow rounds of last digits like it is a float value.

Comment: refer MAX_SAFE_INTEGER https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are floating point numbers. (See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) Therefore the number is converted to its closest representable value. A long random number used as an identifier like that is usually stored as a string.

Comment: Okay, i get your point. But is there any solution for safely using 20digits number in javascript.

Comment: @Vxankit A high quality recommendation might require a bit more context about what you want to achieve but libraries such as this are available: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js